# Why didn't Bastilla Shan give this character back his mask?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

> So Bastilla gave Revans mask to Meetra Surik so she could give it back to Revan to bring back his memories after she freed him from Dromund Kaas. Why didn't Bastilla hand the mask over to Revan before he left in the first place? The whole adventure of finding the Sith Empire etc. would then be superfluous.

Comment: Why would anyone think that giving him his mask would make him remember things?

Comment: I thought that it was common to give people who suffered from amnesia or similar things, objects which might make them remember.

Comment: He didn't suffer from amnesia... his mind was wiped. In all honesty there shouldn't have *been* any memories to recover. But, Bioware decided it wanted a WoW clone MMO instead of another mega popular game of the year RPG, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She didn't think that he would need it. She thought that Darth Malak was the last Sith she thought Revan was going up against the Mandalorians who he had already beaten into submission once already. She didn't think that he would need any extra power or help.

Comment: But when Revan left for the Unknown Regions for the second time might not even a little thing help. Bastilla even says to Meetra that it might help restore Revans memories.

Comment: Like I said she thought the Sith were extinct she had no reason to believe that he was in any danger that he couldn't handle plus she thought he would be with his Mandalorian friend(I forgot to mention that in my answer).